# Java: selection sort stops without any error message

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I'm making a basic program for my computer science class, which is supposed to perform a selection sort on an array. 
Problem is, it stops in the middle of the process and I can't figure out why. 
It used to give me an out of bound exception, which it for some reason doesn't do anymore. 
I'd appreciate if someone could help me fix it.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        int tausch;
        //int size = 10;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int z[] = new int[10];
        for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
            z[i] = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        }
        for(i=0;i<z.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(z[i]+", ");
        }
        
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for(i=0;i<z.length;i++) {
            k = i;
            for(j=i+1;j<10;i++) {
                if(z[k] > z[j]) {
                    k = j;
                }
            }
            tausch = z[i];
            z [i] = z[k];
            z[k] = tausch;
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        
        System.out.println();
        for(i=0;i<z.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(z[i]+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(totalTime);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not increasing variable j in your second loop

Answer (score 0):

`for(j=i+1;j<10;i++)`

Should be `for(j=i+1;j<10;j++)` - you're incrementing the wrong variable.